How to implement multiple themes/designs in a nuxt3 project?
I'm trying to develop a website on nuxt 3 and there is one feature I want to implement, but I have no idea how best to do it. My goal is to implement multiple designs with the ability to switch designs in the admin interface.
I imagine it like this: the database stores the name of the selected design and the options for choosing a design (I have django+graphql on the backend).
The designs should differ from each other not only in colors. In different designs, the same components can have a different size, color, background, border-radius, etc., which means that all styles can differ, but the logic of all elements will be the same.
Important note - I use SSR.
For styles I use tailwindcss, I also use Nuxt UI, PrimeVue, and I wonder if it is possible to implement this at all using these modules?
The design should change for all users of the site
I can use this gql query to get the name of the design I need:
query getDesignName {
    settings {
        designName
    }
}

For example, I have 3 designs (but I plan to increase their number in the future):

Simplicity
Glass morphism
Cartoon

For a clear example of what I want to implement, let's assume that the selected design in the database is “Glass Morphism”. In this case, I want my  component to look like this photo:
Glass morphism design example
And if the selected design is “Cartoon”, this component should already look like this:
Cartoon design example
I've never come across implementing multiple designs before, so I really need some advice/help and would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Your question may get closed, as it is opinion-based and you are seeking resources than having an issue and asking for help. I am very confused of what you do not understand on what to do, the documentation is very clear: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts

@matiaslauriti As far as I know, that's not what NuxtLayout is for. I can specify the basic structure that will be on each page. I have a lot of pages on my site, so it's convenient for me to use NuxtLayout to make sure that each page has a header, footer, and basic styles. I can also make certain pages have a different structure. For example, if I want to have a page without a header and footer (such as a login page), I can create a different Layout for such a page.

@matiaslauriti But, as I described in my question, I have no idea how to create multiple designs. Yes, I can create different layouts and make different headers/footers in different designs, but that's about it. With layout, I don't have the ability to make different templates for different pages in different designs, I don't have the ability to use different components, set different classes, etc.

@matiaslauriti
I had an idea to create a separate layout for each individual page and group them by theme name (theme1-mainpage.vue, theme1-login.vue, theme2-mainpage.vue, etc.), but then I would have to insert the header and footer components manually on EVERY page, because it is impossible to make nested layouts.
So I think my question is quite reasonable and has the right to live.

I understand better now what your issue is. I am not exactly sure if you just change (let's say) CSS or something else, if it is just CSS, you may be able to set a class on the body element, like <body class="theme1">, and in your component, each CSS class or ID must have theme1 as parent, something like this .theme1 > .button, then .theme2 > .button, etc. What I am not sure is, if you scope the styles, I have no idea if .theme1 etc will be correctly read or not, but do you get what I am saying?

@matiaslauriti If I understood your idea correctly, it could be a solution to my problem if different designs differed only in colors/styles, but unfortunately, as I mentioned above (I pinned a links to the photos in my question), in my case, in different designs, elements can be completely different even in html templates, and as of now, I haven't found a solution (at least a good one to work with).
(I know that theoretically this can be done by using a v-if check on the theme name in all project templates, but I think this solution is terrible)
